# What to do in Munich on Christmas Eve?

Tags: germany, munich, christmas

We (me, my wife and our 4-years-old daughter) are now in Munich and are now thinking what to do tomorrow (Dec 24) evening. We don't (or at least were not going to) celebrate Christmas, but apparently almost everything will be closed, including Christmas fairs, stores, restaurants, museums, etc. Is this true, and if yes, then what can you suggest?

Comment: In most European countries Christmas sees everything come to a standstill, even for the majority non-religious people this is the time of the year where people stay with their family. This usually goes from Christmas Eve (evening of the 24th) to the whole Christmas day (the 25th). There have been recent questions on the subject for London and Norway, but I believe it will be mostly the same for Munich. You'll probably only find a handful of restaurants open. Hotel restaurants are often your best bet. In some places, "exotic" restaurants (Chinese, Indian...) may be an option too.

Comment: I'm from Berlin, so I'm not familiar with particular Munich institutions, but you should be aware that in whole Germany the 25th **and** the 26th of December are public holidays. Shops will usually close at early afternoon on the 24th and remain closed for the next 2 days. It is possible to find some institutions like zoo or museums that are open on the 26th, but you should check that in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for things to do on the evening or the whole day?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most restaurants and attractions will close on Christmas Eve at 16:00 or earlier. Even the Christmas Market at the airport will close at 17:00. Many will reopen on the 25th (e.g. Circus Krone, Therme Erding, Sea Life, Hellabrunn zoo).

Stores will usually close in the early afternoon, only some large ones (e.g. supermarkets, electronics) will be open until around 16:00. Stores will stay closed on the 25th and 26th. Shops at the airport, at central station, and many gas stations will also close in the afternoon, but reopen on the 25th.

### Restaurants

[Some](https://muenchen.mitvergnuegen.com/2019/restaurants-an-weihnachtsfeiertagen)  [restaurants](https://www.muenchen.de/essen-trinken/guides/weihnachten-essen.html) (and some [clubs](https://www.muenchen.de/freizeit/weihnachten/party-feiern-an-heiligabend-in-muenchen.html)) will be open on Christmas Eve (in German, try [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) for translations).

### Sightseeing by Tram

Use Tram 19 or 21 from Max-Weber-Platz to Karlsplatz/Stachus, and Tram 17 back to Max-Weber-Platz.

You might ask for more ideas at the [tourist info](https://www.muenchen.de/sehenswuerdigkeiten/tourismus/touristeninformation.html).